# XPage checkbox won't work when opened via notes

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I am having an XPage application with an option to send mail to the registered users with specific link. We basically have options to open it in a Browser and in the Client.
For browser we use an simple http link, however, for notes the mechanism is to use the following:

```
notes://servername/databasepath/XpageName.xsp?OpenXPage&documentId=documentUniqueID&action=editDocument
```

The problem here is that, if we open(using the above link) an XPage containing a custom control with checkbox, it would stay in disabled mode. The same thing works perfectly fine if directly opened in client without using the link. Also, the checkbox stays disabled only when the field binding is done, hence, if there is no field binding, then it works perfectly fine. Is this a bug? (Its kind of pointless to add code here but please let me know if the question is not clear)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

I am having trouble modifying the checkbox value (it stays disabled) from notes client.

Comment: Does it work without the openXPage parameter i.e. using notes://servername/databasepath/XpageName.xsp?action=editDocument&documentId=documentUniqueID ?

Comment: Changing/Removing the openXpage results in opening the default configured page for the application instead of opening the page with the preferred documentId. .

Answer (score 1):

Use `?OpenXPage` instead of `?openXPage`.

That's an interesting behaviour in fact.

If you don't provide `?openXPage` parameter, Notes will not understand what you are looking for and will not open an XPiNC page. When you use this parameter, it understands it should open an XPiNC but there must be some kind of buggy code, because it appends `?OpenXPage` at the end of the action parameter.

However, if you change your url as:

```
notes://servername/databasepath/XpageName.xsp?OpenXPage&documentId=documentUniqueID&action=editDocument
```

It will work. That means `?OpenXPage` parameter is case-insensitive for Notes client but case sensitive for XSP engine.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I don't think so it is case sensitive here since I already had it OpenXpage and not (openXpage) (it was just a small typo in the question assuming that it was not case sensitive)..However, it still doesnt work. I think so it is a bug, I will report it soon (However, I fixed it by removing the checkbox and creating my own onclick event). Thanks a lot though :)

Comment: I have tested that. Make sure you use OpenXPage, not OpenXpage.

Comment: Yes, I have tested it too..give me a day..tomorrow I will put up a code. .